# Detect real native camera resolution on android without interpolation?

Tags: android, image-processing, android-camera

Some smartphones interpolate 8MP camera to 16MP camera.  They sell it as 16MP camera smartphone and there is no way to detect that the real native resolution of the picture is 8MP and that a certain code in android had interpolated the real pixels and made a 16MP photo of it.  But it is blurrier than a real 16MP photo after zooming. How can I detect the number of real detected pixels?  How can I distinguish an interpolated or deformed picture from a non-interpolated 100% real measured picture with full native resolution?

Comment: "that a certain code in android had interpolated the real pixels and made a 16MP photo of it" -- IMHO, it is unlikely that the "certain code" is in Android, but rather is in the camera driver, as that sort of interpolation would be done on a DSP, not by the CPU.